# Limit intranet to certain computers

Tags: vpn, intranet

I've created a intranet website which I would like to limit to only certain computers spread throughout the city, my first thought was creating a vpn server on the web server and authorize the client computers with certificate and then limit the site only to lan. I used SoftEther VPN to setup the server, but a problem I immediately encountered was the slow bandwidth. Now to my actual question is it possible to enable the clients to browse the internet through their own connection and at the same time be able to access the website on the vpn?

**Edit:** I'm also open for other solutions that may be less introsive.

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, enable split tunneling on the VPN.

Comment: on the server side or client side?

Comment: Well, split tunneling requires configuration on both.

Comment: would you mind elobrating, how would I know if the client is using the regular connection for other sites, since when I visit sites it gives me the ip of the vpn still

Comment: [My IP](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=my+ip).

Answer (score 0):

Gather public IPv6 subnets each client is in, and allow them over the Internet. Encrypt with https and secure the web server as it is a public network.

This is not typical. It is more common to have a private network for an intranet, and a fully public network for public facing resources.